# Babel's `path.unshiftContainer()` does not add newly-created vars to scope

Tags: javascript, plugins, babeljs, es6-modules

I am developing a Babel plugin which is often used after `plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` (i.e. source code is ES Modules, but is being transpiled to CommonJS).

My plugin needs to determine if variables used in functions are from an outer scope or globals.

This works fine, except for vars created by `plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`.

Example:

```js
const babel = require('@babel/core');

function myPlugin() {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Program: {
        exit(programPath) {
          // This logic in Program exit visitor
          // to ensure runs after ESM->CJS transform
          programPath.traverse({
            ReferencedIdentifier(path) {
              if (!path.findParent(p => p.isFunction())) return;
              const isGlobal = !path.scope.getBinding(path.node.name);
              path.addComment('leading', isGlobal ? 'global' : 'scoped');
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  };
}

const input = `
  import {x} from './foo.js';
  var y = true;
  function answer() {
    return x && y && console;
  }
`;

const output = babel.transform(input, {
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
    myPlugin
  ]
}).code;

console.log(output);
```

This outputs:

```js
"use strict";
var _foo = require("./foo.js");
var y = true;
function answer() {
  return (/*global*/_foo.x && /*scoped*/y && /*global*/console);
};
```

The problem is `_foo` is not a global, it's a var in top-level scope of the program, so output should include `/*scoped*/_foo.x`. But for some reason `path.scope.getBinding('_foo')` returns `undefined`.

It appears the scope is not updated according to the transform performed by `plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`.

Am I failing to do something I should to ensure the scope gets updated?

**Edit**

Actually it seems this isn't specific to `plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`. It seems to happen with any vars created with `path.unshiftContainer()`.

e.g. Replace `plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` with this plugin in previous example:

```js
function createVarPlugin() {
  return {
    visitor: {
      Program: {
        exit(path) {
          path.unshiftContainer('body', [
            t.variableDeclaration('var', [
              t.variableDeclarator(
                t.identifier('console'),
                t.numericLiteral(123)
              )
            ])
          ]);
        }
      }
    }
  };
}

/* ... */

const output = babel.transform(input, {
  plugins: [ createVarPlugin, myPlugin ]
}).code;
```

now output is:

```js
var console = 123;
import { x } from './foo.js';
var y = true;
function answer() {
  return (/*scoped*/x && /*scoped*/y && /*global*/console);
}
```

This time `console` is wrongly identified as being a global, where it's actually in top-level scope.